# como implementar y cual es la logica de un "mostrar mas"

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, lista, backend

siempre tuve la duda de como es que  se implementa un `mostrar mas`  en una aplicación, supongamos que tengo un endpoint sencillo, que me devuelve un array de productos

```
async function getProducts(res, req){
  const products = await products.find()
  return res.status(200).json(products)
}
```

desde un componente de react los pido al backend y los muestro

```
const AllProducts = () => {
  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 


  useEffect(()=>{
    (async()=>{
      const response = await axios.get("all-products")
      setProducts(response.data)
      setLoading(false)
    })()
  },[])      

  return(
    <>
    {loading ? (
     <p>
      Loading...
     </p>
    ) : (
      <ul>
        {products.map((item, index)=>(
          <li>
           {item.nombre}
           {item.precio}
           {item.cantidades}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )}
    </>
  )
}
```

supongamos que el array de productos tiene exactamente 100 productos, como puedo ir mostrando de a 5, ejemplo: la primera vez que se cargan los productos muestro 5 elementos, luego al dar click en un `mostrar mas` quiero mostrar otros 5 mas, y así sucesivamente.

mis dudas son

1. Esta logica se maneja desde el back o desde el front?
2. No tengo conocimiento de que a un `map` se le ponga un limite, entonces como hago para mostrar solo 5 de 100 ? podria hacer un

---

```
products.map((item, index)=>(
 index === 5 ? null : (
  <li>
    {item.nombre}
    {item.precio}
    {item.cantidades}
  </li>
 )
))
```

pero esto no me va a dejar mostrar mas de 5,

espero entiendan mas o menos lo que planteo, simplemente es una duda que no me puedo sacar todavía

Comment: Yo he notado que usualmente, las respuestas de los endpoints ya tienen un parámetro `page` y el parámetro `data` con registros limitados, por ejemplo de 10 en 10 y así. Saludos

Comment: tu respuesta no cumple con mis expectativas

Comment: Esa logica se basa en la base de datos, Como my sql o calquiera que use sql tienen consultas por paginacion, aprende como hacer paginacion por base de datos, El que te entrega los datos tiene que tener una forma de obtener datos por paginacion, obtener de 10 en 10 ,etc en sql es cuantos items limite y desde que fila.  En firebase es por ref de documento  para continuar la pagina o consulta especifica. En otras apis personalizadas te dan tokens de paginación, como la de youtube.

Comment: La práctica más común es usar parámetros de consulta (como los [*Query String*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string))  desde el front, que indican al servidor la cantidad de documentos que se desean recibir, el paginado se hace en el back. Por ejemplo, en [esta API](https://omnipc.ddns.net/api/quotes?limit=1) realizada por mi, uso un parámetro llamado `limit` que indica el límite de documentos a recibir. La respuesta incluye el número total existente y la página actual que se devuelve. En todo caso, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones, lo cual como bien sabes es motivo de cierre. Saludos

Comment: esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones.

Answer (score 2):

Tu backend debe mostrar desde que
punto hasta otro punto quieres obtener los datos, por ejemplo en esta llamada, debe recibir: cuantos elementos quieres y  desde que punto (puede ser un id)

```
async function getProducts(res, req){
 const id=res.bodyRequest.id
 const amount=res.bodyRequest.amount
 //const products = await products.find()
 const products = await products.findAll({ 
 where: { id , 
 limit: amount
 })
  return res.status(200).json(products)
}
```

debes basarte en la documentacion de sequelize or waterline para hacer las consultas
[https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#findandcountfindoptions-promiseobject](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#findandcountfindoptions-promiseobject)

Comment: ¿Cual dirías tú en base a tu experiencia, es una ventaja de incluir un ORM en un diseño API? Yo hice un ejercicio de diseño de una API muy sencillo y solo use node,mongoDB y express, algo parecido a lo que comenta @OsAndNoTi, pero sin firebase. Saludos